# What's the speed of change of the relative humidity of air inside a greenhouse

Tags: air, humidity

The propagation speed of air humidity is an important variable affecting climate and sanity inside a greenhouse.

High relative humidity of internal air is a typical phenomenon of many greenhouses during the night, that promotes the development of fungus affecting foliage.

I am trying to find a way to measure it, to develop a practical system capable of capturing (condensing) water from the internal humid air in order to decrease its relative humidity.

Lowering the relative humidity of air below a threshold value will lower the incidence of botrytis and another fungus that prosper during humid nights, preventing the application of chemical products and lowering production costs.

If the propagation speed of air humidity is high enough, a single condensing unit will attend a big area of the greenhouse and thus be economical and practical.

I will welcome any idea.

Thanks.